# Switch out vector images for IE7/8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, vector

I am trying to make a site function in IE7/8. I've implemented a script to adapt HTML5 for my client, but I've run into another problem: I'm using Vector images (.SVGs) for some logos and social icons, which cause both IE7 and IE8 to hang on page load.

My question is, is it possible to use some sort of conditional statement to have IE7/8 load, say, a .jpg version of the vectors so it loads the page properly?

Here's what most of these vector images look like in the code:

```
<img src="images/logo.svg" alt="-Company Name-">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to appear only in IE versions below a certain version number, use:

`<!--[if lte IE 8]>`, lte meaning "Less than or equal".

For more on conditional comments, see e.g. the quirksmode.org page.

Example:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]> Displays in IE8 and below only <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> Displays in IE9 and above only <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be much cleaner as a background image using CSS.

```
#svg {
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg');
    width: 667px;
    height: 800px;
    background-size: contain;
}

/* IE6 */
* html #svg { 
    background-image: url('otherurl');
}

/* IE7 */
*+html #svg { 
    background-image: url('otherurl');
}
```

View in modern browser
http://jsbin.com/eVogAdu/1/edit

for IE6 and IE7 only view main page
http://jsbin.com/eVogAdu